# What should we do with the questions that turns out to be incorrect?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, self-answer

I often stumble upon questions that don't provide any kind of SSCCE and are really hard to answer without having the access to the codebase. Usually these kind of questions are left unanswered. But sometimes, later on, after few days it turns out that OP has found a bug in his code and edits his question or posts a comment the goes like this: 'Sorry guys. It turns out that I had a bug in my code. Now I've fixed it and it works.'

Should OP still post the answer to this question even when the answer will not provide any value for other people? Should we close it? If it is left as it is the question stays in the section 'unanswered' and ruins statistics for a tag.

The question I refer to is this one: [Vaadin request to download pdf returns null pointer exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38085688/vaadin-request-to-download-pdf-returns-null-pointer-exception) but I believe I could easily found tons of it.